# How to protect hidden input to be changed by the user

Tags: security, hidden-field

I'm developing an online store website which has several products and user can submit comment for each single product.
So when the user opens a product webpage, they can submit their comments via comment form. In order to do that I've put a hidden input in the comment form which holds the id of the product however, it can be easily manipulated.
I've search a lot and I know that you can never trust data sent by the clients but I suppose there must be a way to make sure that the comment sent is exactly for the product the user is seeing right now. Because user can see a product on the website and change the product id in the hidden input of the comment form and submit it to the server.
Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is it a problem if a user can submit a review for another product? Can't the user review any product anyway? If not: what product is the user allows to review? Have *that* check / verification in the backend.

Comment: User can review every product. I just wanted to make it hard for them to manipulate the data. Is it a waste of time?

Comment: Yes, that is a waste of time. You always need to verify user input for validity, but since any existing productid is valid there is not much to verify.